# Get url parameter and query mysql data with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I want to get a parameter from an url. The url looks like this:

> www.example.com/?v=12345

I want to get the parameter and query my mysql database to get the right data with ajax.

So i have my ajax call here:

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"ajax2.php",
dataType:"json",
success:function(response){
var id = response['id'];
var url = response['url'];
var name = response['name'];
var image = response['image'];
},
error:function(response){

alert("error occurred");
}
});
```

As you can see, the data which i want to get are in a json array and will be saved in javascript variables.

This is my php file:

```
 <?php

 // Connection stuff right here

 $myquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable **WHERE id= **$myurlvariable**;
 $result = mysql_query($myquery);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
$currentid = "$row->id";
$currentname = "$row->name";
$currenturl = "$row->url";
$currentimage = "$row->image";
$array = array('id'=>$currentid,'url'=>$currenturl, 'name'=>$currentname,'image'=>$currentimage);

 echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

The part where i want to query the right variable is bolded. I don't know how to query that. And Furthermore how to even get the url parameter in the proper form.

Can anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: Please, don't use the `mysql_*` functions, especialy when you are writing new code, they are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. Your code will stop working then. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects and use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the query string using JavaScript and send it in the AJAX request.

Getting the query string(JavaScript) -

```
function query_string(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}
//Getting the parameter-
v = query_string('v');  // Will return '12345' if url is www.example.com/?v=12345
```

This needs to be passed as data in the AJAX call.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type:       "POST",
        dataType:   "json",
        url:        "ajax2.php",
        data:       "v="+v,
        success:    function(response){
                        var id = response['id'];
                        var url = response['url'];
                        var name = response['name'];
                        var image = response['image'];
                    },
        error:      function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    //alert(textStatus);
                    //alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR)+" "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
                    //alert("error occurred");
                }
    }
);
```

This can be accessed as $_POST['v'] in the php form.

```
if(isset($_POST['v'])){
$myurlvariable = $_POST['v'];
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id= $myurlvariable";
...
```

And in php form, before you echo out the json response, change the content type. Something like this-

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
```

If there is a database error, then it has to be handled.
So do this -

```
<?php
    // Connection stuff right here
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    if(isset($_POST['v'])){
        $myurlvariable = $_POST['v'];
        $myquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id= $myurlvariable";
        $result = mysql_query($myquery) or die(json_encode(Array("error": mysql_error()));
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            $currentid = "$row->id";
            $currentname = "$row->name";
            $currenturl = "$row->url";
            $currentimage = "$row->image";
            $array[]= array('id'=>$currentid,'url'=>$currenturl, 'name'=>$currentname,'image'=>$currentimage);
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
    }else{
        echo json_encode(Array("error": "No POST values"));
    }
?>
```

So this way, if the query has not executed properly, then you will know what exactly the error is.

Comment: Error: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=

Comment: It should be  $myurlvariable = $_GET['v']; instead of $_POST['v'] = $myurlvariable; ?

Comment: It seems to be a database error. Check the edit. I have added a check for mysql_query and also, in your ajax call, check the error:function(...)

Comment: No, it won't be $GET_['v'] because in your AJAX call, you are making a POST request by making type: 'POST'

Comment: Try alerting the value before you make the ajax call and also Echo the value in the php file.

Comment: Ok post, but shouldn't it be the other way round, so that $myurlvariable gets the value of $_POST['v']

Comment: Oh Oh! I am really sorry, it's a typo on my part. It should be  $myurlvariable = $_POST['v']; instead of $_POST['v'] = $myurlvariable;...

Comment: The alert before the ajax call is fine. How can i see the value of $myurlvariable (echo it) when i am calling the ajax request in index.php but the php script is running in ajax.php

Comment: By echoing out $myurlvariable, you are making your response non-json, hence the error callback in AJAX will be called and as I have written in the script, you will get to see the contents of what was returned in the alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR)+" "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);

Comment: parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Comment: Check the edit. I have added php code in such a way that now it will always output json even if there is an error. If there is an error, it will create an object {"error": "error_type"}. You can alert it in your success: function(response){alert(JSON.stringify(data));}

Comment: I have no idea what changed, i uploaded the documents again and everything works perfectly like i wanted it! Thank you so much! Thank you for your patience wouldn't have made it without you!

Comment: @Kamehameha, This is somewhat similar to.... what I am trying to accomplish. But missing direction. I have a Q on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192531/add-editable-textbox-to-specific-datapoint-in-a-chart. I progressed on this Q by calling jquery dialog and ajax calls. I am struggling hard to associate the datapoint click to the mysql ID associated with that datapoint. Any inputs are helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without any error checking, just the important part:

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=" . $_POST['v'];
```

Comment: You mean  $_GET['v'] ? because it's a URL parameter